# Does BatchNormalization count as a layer in a network?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

Is BatchNormalizationLayer considered a layer in a neural network?
For example, if we say, Resnet50 has 50 layers, does that mean that some of those layers may be batchnormalization layers?

When building models in Keras I considered it as an extra, similar to a dropout layer or when adding an “Activation layer”. But BatchNormalization  has trainable parameters, so... I am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DeepLearning literature, an `X` layer network simply refers to the usage of learnable layers that constitute the representational capacity of the network.
Activation layers, normalization layers (such as NLR, BatchNorm, etc), Downsampling layers (such as Maxpooling, etc) are not considered.

Layers such as `CNN`, `RNN`, `FC`, and the likes that are responsible for the representational capacity of the network are counted.

Comment: That is where my question arises. I saw that BatchNorm has trainable parameters in Keras. How does that work? Thank you Rika!

Comment: It has learnable parameters gamma and beta that are used specifically for normalization. they do not add to the network's representational capacity, they make training easier!
let's put it this way, if you only use BN layers in a network will you learn any features that describe your input data? on the other hand, if you use any form of layers such as CNN, FC, etc in your network, you can indeed reach a set of features that represent your input data in a new form. this is what's considered in the literature.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how precise you define what a "layer" is. This may vary for different authors.

For your [ResNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) example it is pretty clear: In Section 3.4 *Implementation* you'll a description of the network, there it say's:

> We adopt batch normalization (BN) right after each convolution and
> before activation, [...].

So convolution and batch normalization is considered as a single layer. Figure 3. in the paper shows a picture of ResNet34 where the batch normalization layers are not even explicitly shown and the layers sum up to 34.

So in conclusion, the ResNet paper does not count batch normalization as extra layer.

Further Keras makes it really easy to check those things for many [pretrained models](https://keras.io/api/applications/), e.g.:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
resnet = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50()
print(resnet.summary())
```